# How to redirect '%3e' or '>' in .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

Apologies if this has been covered before. I've looked, but I am new to this forum and first time poster.

I'm picking up `%3e` character on the end of some links. An erroneous `>` somewhere I'm sure, which I'm trying to track down. Even with validators help it's a tough one.

In the meantime, what is the syntax to redirect in htaccess please? 
i.e simply remove that character.

Tried but not working:

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)(\s|%3e)(.+)$ /$1$3 [R=301,QSA,L,NE]
```

Comment: Which syntax? where you want to place? first of all put some code that you have tried

Comment: Provide an example of URI you want to rewrite and what you want to rewrite to.

Comment: RewriteRule ^(.+)(\s|%3e)(.+)$ /$1$3 [R=301,QSA,L,NE] - This did not appear to work, but similar ones like this do. Any advice very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Although you see `%3e` in the URL, you want to match on `>` as this is the actual character that is decoded and sent to the server. This pattern will match and redirect any link with a `>` at the end.

```
# Enable mod_rewrite and set the base directory
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule (.*)?(>)$ $1 [R=301,NC,QSA,L]
```

- `(.*)?` = any character, not greedy due to the ?
- `(>)$` = the `>` at the end of the URL
- `[R=301]` = perform a 301 redirect
- `[NC]` = No Case (case insensitive)
- `[QSA]` = Query String Append (include the querystring in the redirect)
- `[L]` = Last rule (stop processing further rules)

Test using http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/

As a side note this probably means you are missing a closing on one of you `<A>`nchor tags href property. For example `<a href="http://example.com/page>My Link</a>` Will result in a URL in your browser of `http://example.com/page%3e`.

Comment: That's just what I needed. Thank you very much.

Comment: Great, if this worked for you it would be appreciated if you could mark it as the answer for others.